# Searching a range when using like %

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm searching SQL Server using the following and I want to find a way to reduce the query size when it comes to the range of postal codes being searched:

```
SELECT TOP (100) *
  FROM XXXX (NOLOCK)
  WHERE (Request like '%<BillCountry>US</BillCountry>%')
  AND (Request like '%<BillPostal>83%' OR Request like '%<BillPostal>84%' OR Request like '%<BillPostal>85%' OR Request like '%<BillPostal>86%' OR Request like '%<BillPostal>87%' OR Request like '%<BillPostal>91%' OR Request like '%<BillPostal>92%' OR Request like '%<BillPostal>93%' OR Request like '%<BillPostal>94%')
  AND (CreatedUTC between '2022-02-01' and '2022-03-01')
  ORDER BY CreatedUTC DESC
```

The `<BillPostal>XXXXX</BillPostal>` is deep inside a saved XML response.
I'm searching for a range of BillPostal such as 83XXX-87XXX and 91XXX-94XXX. Maybe this is the only way?

Comment: `NOLOCK` won't make a slow query go fast or take no locks. It will take *a schema lock on the entire table* but ignore existing locks. This can result in dirty data, *duplicate rows* and the occasional error. You can't use `LIKE %` to parse XML either. If you want efficient searching change the type to `xml`, create an index over the XML field and use XML operators to query the XML data

Comment: `LIKE '%blah%'` can't take advantage of any index. What you try to do right now will always scan the entire table. Using `NOLOCK` won't change that, or make it go faster

Comment: If you have a valid xml document why not use XQuery?

Comment: Check [XML Data Type and Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) Also consider *not* using XML but using proper columns for BillCountry and BillPostal. If you already know you'll want to query those fields, why burry them inside an XML string? Even with an XML index, querying will be slower

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: If you disregard it being xml you could put your strings in a lookup table and join to it/use *exists* with `charindex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql Server you can use a character class `[]` in the pattern syntax for LIKE/PATINDEX.

So the criteria for Request can be golfcoded

```
SELECT TOP (100) *
FROM XXXX 
WHERE (Request like '%<BillCountry>US</BillCountry>%')
  AND (Request like '%<BillPostal>8[3-7]%' 
    OR Request like '%<BillPostal>9[1-4]%')
  AND (CreatedUTC between '2022-02-01' and '2022-03-01')
ORDER BY CreatedUTC DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could offload the bulk of your criteria to an *exists* check with the lookup terms in a separate table. An example would be:

```
with lookups as (
 select '<BillPostal>83' term union all
 select '<BillPostal>84' union all
 select '<BillPostal>85' 
), testdata as (
  select '<xml><element><BillPostal>85</billpostal></element></xml>' col union all
  select '<xml><element><BillPostal>81</billpostal></element></xml>' union all
  select '<xml><element><BillPostal>86</billpostal></element></xml>' union all
  select '<xml><element><BillPostal>84</billpostal></element></xml>'
)
select * 
from testdata
where exists (select * from lookups where CharIndex(term,col) > 0);
```